# Attachment Not Sending with Laravel Mail

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send an email with Laravel and attach a generated PDF to the email. The email is sending but the pdf isn't being sent.

Notes:
Using Larvel Version 5.5
PHP version >=7.0.0
Library I'm using to generate pdf: https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf

Here is the code:

```
<?php

namespace Portal\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use niklasravnsborg\LaravelPdf\Facades\Pdf as PDF;

class PreApprovalEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $name;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $this->subject('Pre approval letter');

        return $this->view('emails.emailTemplate')->attachData($this->createPDF(), 'generated.pdf', [
            'mime' => 'application/pdf',
        ]);
    }

    public function createPDF()
    {
        $data = array(
            // data
        );

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('emails.generatablePDF', $data);
        return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');         
    }
}
```

Here is the route in my routes/web.php file:

```
Route::get('/samplemail', function () { 
    Mail::to("<my_email>@protonmail.com")->send(new PreApprovalEmail("test"));
    return view('emails.generatablePDF')
});
```

According to the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail) I should be getting the proper email, including the attachment. I am getting the email, but not the attachment. How can I solve this?

Comment: remove $data from loadView method and try.

Comment: I tried removing $data but I still don't get the attachment - either way the view requires the $data

Comment: okay then try with compact('data')

Answer (score 2):

Can you try `output` method for your pdf instead of streaming it, as stream first calls the output then builds a new http response:

```
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $this->subject('Pre approval letter');

        return $this->view('emails.emailTemplate')
            ->attachData($this->createPDF(), 'generated.pdf');
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function createPDF()
    {
        $data = [
            // data
        ];

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('emails.generatablePDF', $data);
        return $pdf->output();
    }
```

Also make sure that your pdf output is correct so do a `dd` before attaching it to the email.