# Laravel 9 - ERROR: The body of "Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\TextPart" must be a string or a resource (got "Illuminate\Http\Response")

Tags: php, email, upgrade, laravel-9

after upgrade from Laravel 6 to 9, i have this error...

Below is my code that produce the error:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('general.layouts.pdf.receipt_paid');

$pdf_name = "PAID RECEIPT_123456";
$pdf_stream = $pdf->stream($pdf_name);

Mail::send('general.email.receipt', [], function($message) use($pdf_stream, $pdf_name){
    $message->to("johndoe@gmail.com")
    ->subject('Your Order (123456) Has Been Paid')
    ->attachData($pdf_stream, $pdf_name, [
        'mime' => 'application/pdf'
    ]);
});
```

I don't have any idea what is the mistake I made... or do I need to amend something after upgrade to version 9?

I already try use `Mailable` class instead, but still occurred the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved the problem...

Actually it is not related with Laravel upgrade...

But actually it has problem with `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` newer version...

After upgrade `laravel-dompdf`, I need to use `$pdf->output()` instead of `$pdf->stream($pdf_name)`..

Then my problem solved..

The solution is based on this question actually:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60947707/5179633